Error: Target container is not a DOM element. Test React Vitest
Issue:
An "Error: Target container is not a DOM element" occurs when running tests for a React component that utilizes Firebase to add documents.
Observed Behavior:

The application functions correctly in production without any errors, and documents are successfully added.
The error only appears during test execution.
The source of the error seems to be the addDoc function from Firebase, even after mocking it.

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Isolating individual components confirmed that the error is related to addDoc.
Mocking addDoc did not resolve the issue.

Mock of Firebase:
vi.mock("firebase/firestore", async (importOriginal: any) => {
    const firestore = await importOriginal();
    return {
        ...firestore,
        collection: vi.fn(),
        addDoc: vi.fn(),
    };
});

addDocuments function:
const addDocuments = async () => {
    try {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        await addDoc(collection(db, "user"), {
            name: ID_USER,
            score: score,
            date: currentDate,
        });
        console.log("ici");
        setSent(true); // Set the state to true after adding the document
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
};    

Firebase initialization :
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Firebase configuration
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db }

